# a HashSet.contains() returning an Object

Tags: java, performance, collections, hashset, asymptotic-complexity

Suppose i'm working a type `A` in Collections.

```
class A {
    ThisType thisField; 
    ThatType thatField; 
    String otherField; 
}
```

Only `thisField` and `thatField` are relevant to identify the instances of `A`-- so its `equals()` and along with it `hashCode()` methods are overridden accordingly. 
With this, in a `HashSet<A> setOfAs`, the objects of `A` are unique across their (`thisField`,`thatField`) value pair.

Somewhere in the application, i need to look up the `Set` for an instance of `A` and if it exists, print its `otherField`-- the meta-info.

i can

i.)  get an iterator on `setOfAs`, see each entry for its `thisField` and `thatField` values, and if they both match, print its `otherField`

ii.) use a self-map, `HashMap<A,A> selfMapA`, where key and value are the same objects in each entry. instantiate `A` with (`thisField`,`thatField`) value pair to look-up `selfMapA` and get its matching entry as is if it's there.

(i) is `O(n)`-- doesn't get the object in constant time although it finds it in constant time.

(ii) gets the object in constant time and is what we keep using in the system. however, it's using twice the memory.

what i'm looking for is a set structure getting the object entry that it finds in constant time. for instance, one with a 
`contains(Object)` method returning an `Object`, the object it found if it exists, rather than `boolean` as `HashSet.contains()` does.

are there better alternatives to these? is there a way to get around this?

Comment: maybe HashMap.get(Object key) then check if it returns null is constant, im not sure though

Comment: With the problem as you've described it, the correct answer is the accepted one, but your set up is a bit odd. Why don't you just remove the field `otherField` and use a `HashMap<A, String>`?

Comment: @pbabcdefp that too could be. however in the existing system would require changing the types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HashSet is implemented using a HashMap with all values set to a dummy object, so option 2 should actually use slightly less memory than a HashSet. I would go with option 2.

Comment: i'll look into the source. not clear for now what you're saying.

Comment: not yet looked up but convinced. where did my prev.comment go?

Comment: A `HashSet` takes no more memory then a `HashMap` since the dummy object is the class constant `private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();`.

Comment: @maaartinus: The extra memory is for the HashSet object itself.

Answer (score 0):

As User235... says, HashSet is implemented using a HashMap so the memory use difference between the two is negligible. This has constant time addition and lookup, so time complexity wise you can't do better. So with that in mind, using a hashmap is probably the best answer.

```
public class Database<A>{
    private HashMap<A,A> db = new HashMap<A,A>();

    /** Adds a to this database. If there was already a in this database,
     * overwrites the old a - updates the metaData 
     */
    public void add(A a){
        db.put(a,a);
    }

    /** Removes a from this database, if present */
    public void remove(A a){
        db.remove(a);
    }

    /** Returns the metadata associated with a in this database.
     * As instances of A hash on thisField and thatField, this
     * may be a different string than a.otherField.
     * Returns null if a is not present in this database.
     */
    public String getMetaData(A a){
        A dat = db.get(a);
        return dat != null ? dat.otherField : null;
    }
}
```